# Responsive UI Tips

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would just like a few tips when i want to create a responsive UI.

I know how to use:

```
Dispatcher
Task
BackgroundWorker
Threads
```

I am looking for more advance tips, like binding tips... When i have 50+ controls on my UI that needs to update.

```
PriorityBinding
Populating ComboBoxes
Populating ListBoxes, ListViews
```

When processing data in the background...
Best practices maybe when it comes to long running proccess.

What else can i do to make my UI 100% responsive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. [FastObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687000/fast-performing-and-thread-safe-observable-collection)
2. Manipulating [PresentationSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.presentationsource.aspx)
3. Using [PLinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) or Linq on multiple threads by using
   [AsQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx)() for dynamic filtering of data sources than single threaded and thread agnostic `CollectionView`.
4. Readymade [Gifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf) over animation
5. Vitualization of non-virtualized panels like canvas
6. Deferred scrolling
7. Trigger.Exnter \ Exit Actions for animations.
8. BeginStoryboard.HandoffBehavior="Compose"
9. Using Hardware over software acceleration.
10. Avoiding `WindowStyle=None`, `AllowTransparency=true`, `Background=Transparent`, `TileMode`
11. Configure `RenderOptions.BitmpaScalingMode` as LowQuality and enable caching. Enable `PresentationFontCache` windows service.
12. Use `Staticresources` over `Dynamicresources`
13. Avoid inheritable dependency properties. Also avoid heavy operations in property changed call backs.
14. Use Freezable brushes. Avoid `x:Name` / `Namescoping` / `Binding` to their `Color` propertys them to be freezable all the time.
15. Set background of the border, if it encapsulates a visual than setting visual's background. Similar is if you have set a `Brush` as background of a visual then specify `Brush.Opacity` than `Visual.Opacity`.
16. Value converters must have minimulistic code. use `Binding.IsAsync` and `PriorityBinding` wherever applicable.
17. Use `Expanders` with `IsExpanded=False` by default.
18. `CompositionTarget.Rendering` fires on each rendering cycle so should be used only if required. Detatch it on any opportunity.
19. WPF `DataGrid` should avoid heavy use of combobox columns and editable Template columns, as the combobx templates try to load selected value and use the display member path by actually searching it from the items source of **each** combobox and template columns leak when used with highly observable collections.
20. Use WPF Extedned Tooklit based Shader effects and New Pixel Shader APIs
    such as Blur, Shadow.

And Many more...

Comment: Eventually disabling all best graphics and make app look like old style win 32 app :)

Answer (score 1):

I always found lazy loading very helpful to prevent large data amounts being loaded at once, which is where most of the startup time goes when handling large amounts of data. Bind your records to [virtualized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing.aspx) item controls, to minimize the memory footprint (obviously WPF is your judge on what's necessary in memory).

But to be honest : Martin is quite right...50+ databound controls,...man, that's freakin' hell ;-)

And your quest for 100% responsiveness, I guess, needs further explanation. To my understanding, applications can be responsive or not (taking user input / producing output vs being stuck doing nothing). Do you aim best performance? Or is it a rowlocking-scenario you're facing (let the user edit other records while performing long tasks on certain records)?

I think some of what AngelWPF has mentioned can be found in [this neat article](http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/PriorityBinding-in-WPF) on priority binding.

Comment: Yea, 50+ controls seems allot, but they are all equally important. The part that takes the longest time is the bindings for the item's source on my combos... But the initial loading of the Form(View) takes a very long time. I want the form up quick and then the rest of the bindings can happen or something like that. When the user clicks on the drop down that takes a long time to open as well, because of the massive amount of data... So i am a bit stuck

Comment: OK, if that's any help, check out the information in this post : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

50+ controls on a single UI sounds like it was designed by a coder and optimising the code will probably just offset the real problem for a while. Best thing to speed that up is to seperate your functionality out onto different screens or hide the less used information behind menus.