# Thread problems in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, dispatcher, background-thread

You cannot bind to a WPF `DataGrid's` Columns property, so a workaround is to use use an attached property as found [in this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns). My viewmodel exposes an `ObservableCollection` containing the `DataGridColumns`, and I bind it to the `DataGrid` via this attached property.

A background thread is responsible for populating the collection, and I'm using `Dispatcher.Invoke` to do this, which I thought would avoid threading issues. The background thread itself works fine, but an exception is raised in the above attached property code:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

(in the `else if` that deals with an Add action, specifically the line `dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);`).

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687000/fast-performing-and-thread-safe-observable-collection

Comment: Could you build the ObservableCollection in the background.  But then on the main (UI) thread add the columns?

Comment: @Blam not sure I follow. The ObservableCollection *is* my collection of columns. I'm using MVVM and this attached property is the only way to bind the columns at runtime (I don't know what columns I need at design-time so can't create them in XAML). The background thread performs a number of tasks - retrieves data, populates a collection to bind to the grid rows, and populates the columns collection. As a last resort I could move this last step out of the background thread and into the UI thread. Creating a dozen items doesn't warrant it being in a background thread.

Comment: If creating a dozen items does not warrant being on a background thread then why is it a "last resort".   What part don't you follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.5, the simplest option is to use [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845.aspx).   This allows you to update a collection on a background thread directly, without worrying about synchronization in the binding.

Otherwise, you need to make sure that all changes to your collection happen on the user interface thread.  Using `Dispatcher.Invoke` should work (provided you get the correct `Dispatcher` instance), though there are more elegant solutions, such as the binding collections in [The Helper Trinity](http://thehelpertrinity.codeplex.com/) and other projects.

Comment: I'm using 4.0. I think I'm using the correct Dispatcher instance. If I put a breakpoint in the code and look at the Dispatcher's Thread.ManagedThreadID, it's the same as the main thread's ID. Similarly when the exception is raised, the thread window is showing as being in the main thread. Not sure what else I can check to confirm that I'm on the right threads everywhere.

Comment: @AndrewStephens Make sure that your collection and the binding was *created*  on the main UI thread, too...

Comment: Marked as answer as it was almost there, and inspired me to find the problem! Although I was adding my DataGridColumn objects to the ObservableCollection using Dispatcher.Invoke, I wasn't *creating* them using a Dispatcher, i.e. they were "owned" by the background thread - hence the exception message.