# Thread hangs when updating ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a javafx application which has a ListView supported by an ObservableList.

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> taggedQueriesResultsList;
private ObservableList<String> searchResultsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

The ObservableList is updated with data, say `list.add("something")`, by a scheduled task using `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`. However the scheduled task never runs after the first time. The UI is updated after the first run. I have noticed that if I comment out the line `list.add("something")` the task runs periodically as scheduled.

I think this is some synchronisation issue but not sure. Please help me understand what is going on and how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you always update the GUI from the application thread. See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

For a thread safe ObservableCollection, see here: [Fast performing and thread safe observable collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687000/fast-performing-and-thread-safe-observable-collection)

Comment: the second link to Fast performing and thread safe observable collection is for c#. this question is regarding java.

Answer (score 0):

An example where is created a synchronized Observable list:

```
newSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> listaSerie;
listaSerie = FXCollections.synchronizedObservableList(FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>()));
newSeries.setData(listaSerie);
```