# C# performance: construct new collection with existing items using constructor or loop?

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library, observablecollection

I've searched but not found answer, maybe because this question is not easy to describe.
For example in WPF, I have a model `Test`, and a `List<Test> lst`, then have to construct a `ObservableCollection<TestViewModel> ObsTests`. There maybe 2 ways:

1. ```
   var ObsTests = new ObservableCollection<TestViewModel>(lst
       .Select(t = > new TestViewModel(t));
   ```
2. ```
   var ObsTests = new ObservableCollection<TestViewModel>();
   foreach(var test in lst)
   {
       ObsTests.Add(new TestViewModel(test));
   }
   ```

Please tell me which is better in performance, and tell me the best solution if `AsParallel` is available(such as **is ObservableCollection threadsafe**? I'm using .net **4.5**)

Comment: Hint: if you have a performance issue; then start profiling. If you don't have a perfomance issue; then focus on writing easy-to-read code.

Comment: I have performance issue, but there are too many combinations, adding parallel for example, and I think it is a valuable common question for all developers.

Comment: First and second approaches are identical in performance. When you pass in collection into ObservableCollection it performs foreach loop inside in ctor.

Comment: @Carl from nopeflow's answer, I know now too... thx

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: You might want to look at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx)  or  AsParallel which in some cases can improve performance.

Comment: @apc I already know that. but there are too many choices for Task, Parellel, even regarding Parellel, there are ForAll, Foreach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. Ctor uses `Add` method from base class `Collection`:
Reffer: [click](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,0a94f24cf8df29b2,references)!

```
public ObservableCollection(List<T> list)
    : base((list != null) ? new List<T>(list.Count) : list)
{
    CopyFrom(list);
}

private void CopyFrom(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    IList<T> items = Items;
    if (collection != null && items != null)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                items.Add(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ObservableCollection` basis on `Collection` so it is not thread-safe.
For thread-safe collection - use some class from `Concurrent` namespace. More on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also implement own-super-fast observable collection. Like here:
[Click!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687000/fast-performing-and-thread-safe-observable-collection)

Comment: Then is there a Concurrent collection which implements **INotifyCollectionChanged**?

Comment: No - but see my last words - i have added link to custom implementation.

Comment: how do you consider **Parallel** here? will it improve(and how)?

Answer (score -1):

In case if you have standard implementation of some action, and can do the same using your code, it is better to choose the standard implementation. Also it looks more tiny :)

Comment: What you say seems to apply to all questions.