# Why does ObservableCollection have a user interface related limitation?

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm building a WPF application and while creating my domain model I used `ObservableCollection<T>`.
I allowed myself to use it only because it clearly belongs to the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace.

During execution I received an error. I found a thread in SO already deals with the problem in here: [Where do I get a thread-safe CollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137769/where-do-i-get-a-thread-safe-collectionview)

My question is: assuming `ObservableCollection<T>` is in System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace, why does it have a user interface related limitation? Is it an architecture flaw or intended? Is it good practice to use it in domain model?

Comment: THat's not a title, that's an illness.

Comment: It's not a limitation of the `ObservableCollection<T>`, that's a limitation of WPF.

Comment: H.B - please accept my appologies - this is the 1st time I use SO to ask a question - will improve my titles in the future :)

Comment: svick - is that mean that when the collection is not bounded I will have no problem adding items to it from a non-ui thread?

Comment: This is a limitation of CollectionView, not ObservableCollection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't view this as a design flaw at all. And we use them in our WPF domain models. We just make sure that anytime we update our observable collections, we do so on the UI thread. This is very easy to do. We've also created our own implementation so that anytime we update our observable collections, we disable the collection updated method until all items have been added or removed. This greatly increases binding performance.

Comment: but what happens if I want to update the collection from a non-ui process? what happens if I had no UI in my app - would I be getting the same error when trying to update? - if so it is clearly not belong to the objectModel namespace.

Comment: If you have no UI, or a non-UI process, why are you using an ObservableCollection? These are primarily used for binding to WPF UI objects.

Comment: because I want the functionality of notify when somthing is changed in the collection... it is very helpful in the domain model. but if it was not designed to be independent / in the BL layer - I would not use it.

Comment: You can easily do this without using an ObservableCollection.