# ListBox throws ItemControl Text Visualizer error when scrolling

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a listbox, code below, that I'm populating with 900 items.  When I scroll down the list quickly I get an exception of 'An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source'.  Any ideas as to what is causing the issue?

```
                <ListBox x:Name="FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                     MaxHeight="520" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="FileChecked" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding Source}" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource FileProperties}" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding Destination}" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource FileProperties}"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding ArchiveLocation}" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource FileProperties}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGVGW.png)

Here is a video of the issue.  https://www.screencast.com/t/YUlp24zoXiG

Comment: Is the list of files changing from somewhere else? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22528015/1383366

Comment: Nope, see the video below of the issue.
https://www.screencast.com/t/YUlp24zoXiG

Comment: Can I see the definition of `Files` and how those are populated?

Comment: public List<InstrumentFile> Files
        {
            get
            {
                return _Files;
            }
            set
            {
                _Files = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Files"));
            }
        }

Comment: List<InstrumentFile> _Files { get; set; }

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary there (other than `_Files` being a property rather than a field, but I don't think that's an issue). Make sure neither `Files` nor `_Files` is being changed anywhere else. If you can share your full code somewhere (e.g., GitHub), I can take a deeper look.

Comment: Here is the github link.  Thanks Redcurry.  https://github.com/btbowden/wcla/tree/master/WCLA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the problem. I've pasted the problematic code below, so that other visitors can benefit from this answer.

```
// Your code from GitHub unchanged
private async void Preview_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vm.Files = new List<InstrumentFile>();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < InstrumentList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ListBoxItem lbi = (InstrumentList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)) as ListBoxItem;
            ContentPresenter cp = GetFrameworkElementByName<ContentPresenter>(lbi);
            DataTemplate dt = InstrumentList.ItemTemplate;
            CheckBox cb = (dt.FindName("InstrumentChecked", cp)) as CheckBox;

            if (cb.IsChecked == true)
            {
                List<InstrumentFile> instrumentFiles = new List<InstrumentFile>();
                Instrument instrument = ((Instrument)(InstrumentList.Items[i]));

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(instrument.FileSource);
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                    instrumentFiles.Add(new InstrumentFile()
                    {
                        Name = fi.Name,
                        Source = instrument.FileSource,
                        Destination = instrument.Destination,
                        ArchiveLocation = instrument.ArchiveLocation
                    });
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrument.FileExt) == false)
                {
                    IEnumerable<InstrumentFile> filteredFiles = instrumentFiles.Where(f => f.Name.ToUpper().EndsWith(instrument.FileExt.ToUpper()));
                    if (filteredFiles.Count() > 0)
                        vm.Files.AddRange(filteredFiles);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (instrumentFiles.Count > 0)
                        vm.Files.AddRange(instrumentFiles);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Exception Encountered", ex.Message, MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative, Helpers.DialogSettings());
    }
    FileCount.Content = vm.Files.Count.ToString() + " files";
}
```

Here, you're initializing the `Files` property in the view model. This causes the data-binding to be updated to an empty list. There's no problem so far. However, you then add things to `Files`, but these changes are not propagated to the data-binding system because the list in the view model is not an `ObservableCollection`.

You can fix this problem in a couple of ways. One type of fix is to set the `Files` property in the view model *after* you've created and filled the list. The new code would look like this (abbreviated):

```
private async void Preview_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create new variable to store the list
    var files = new List<InstrumentFile>();

    // You do a bunch of things, but you now add items to files, not to vm.Files
    files.AddRange(filteredFiles);

    // Finally, change Files
    vm.Files = files
}
```

That last line will raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the view model to update the data-binding, but will do so with the full list of items.

The second kind of fix is to change the type of `Files` in your view model to `ObservableCollection<InstrumentFile>`. Any time you make a change to `Files`, the correct event will be raised to update the data-binding.

Comment: Thank you Redcurry!  You fixed it.