# Getting thread access exceptions on OnCollectionChanged after Creators Update

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifycollectionchanged, cross-thread

In my program, I have an abstract class `ObservableKeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` that inherits from `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` and also implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

A realisation of this abstract class is bound to a `ListBox`. In this `ListBox`, I edit items on double click, and upon acceptance, I remove the old instance of the edited item from this `ObservableKeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` realisation, and add the new instance that has been modified.

It all worked well before Windows 10 Creators Update (1703, build number 15063.250). Since the update, `ObservableKeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` started throwing `InvalidOperationException`s with the following message:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I do not use any async operations in this region of the code.

The whole stack trace would be too long but here is the top part starting with `OnCollectionChanged`:

> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
>      at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.GetIsSelected(DependencyObject element)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.ItemSetIsSelected(ItemInfo info, Boolean value)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.CreateDeltaSelectionChange(List'1 unselectedItems, List'1 selectedItems)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.RemoveFromSelection(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemCollectionChanged2(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.OnViewCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList'1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
>      at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEventToList(Object sender, EventArgs args, ListenerList list)
>      at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
>      at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args, Int32 adjustedOldIndex, Int32 adjustedNewIndex)
>      at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>      at TetheredSun.ObservableKeyedCollection'2.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) at e:\Phil\Programozás\Modulok\TetheredSun.1.0\TetheredSun\ObservableKeyedCollection.cs, line number: 68
>      at TetheredSun.ObservableKeyedCollection`2.RemoveItem(Int32 index) at [...]

**Edit 1:**

Here is the offending code section that worked all right before Creators Update (an override of `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>.RemoveItem(int index)`
) :

```
protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
{
    TItem item = this[index];
    base.RemoveItem(index);
    if (deferNotifyCollectionChanged) return;
    if (item is IList) {
        // Listeners do not support multiple item changes, and our item happens to be an IList, so we must raise NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset.
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    } else {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
    }
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
}
```

The problem seems to occur only if I invoke `OnCollectionChanged` with the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove` action. Replacing it with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` seems to avert the exception:

```
protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
{
    TItem item = this[index];
    base.RemoveItem(index);
    if (deferNotifyCollectionChanged) return;
    // No exception thrown so far if I stick to NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
}
```

I have tried to solve the problem with a `Dispatcher` as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22026686/2659699 but though my dispatcher is not null, its `CheckAccess()` evaluates to true, and I keep getting the same exception upon `NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke()`.

Your thoughts and assistance are greatly appreciated.

Comment: We've experienced the exact same thing internally. Sad to not see any answers on this! Did you ever find an answer for this? :-)

Comment: @Simon Gustavsson: I have not found anything yet. I linked this page in an Insider survey, so Microsoft might be aware of it if they are thorough.

At the moment I use the workaround above, that is, to use `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` wherever I used to apply `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove`. It must be wasteful but at the list size I am using I cannot notice any performance hit.

Comment: Ugh. I think I am seeing this issue. And I'm only seeing it on certain machines and not others ...

Comment: Changing to a Reset action instead of a Remove action fixes our issue.

Comment: We saw this issue on a Windows 7 machine too ... so for us, it does not seem completely related to the Windows 10 Creators Update.

Comment: It might make sense to file a Microsoft Connect issue on this. It sure feels like a Microsoft bug.

Comment: I just added a Microsoft Connect issue myself. We just observed a second instance of this error. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3141688

Comment: @cplotts: I think, I have the same issue. Changing the notification action from Remove to Replace seams to solve the same issue. More investigation is done on Monday.

Comment: @Arthur Hopefully Microsoft contacts me today. I plan to try and create a test application for them to reproduce it. Is your issue also only on certain machines? Ours happens on some machines but not others, and I haven't been able to pin it down.

Comment: @cplotts: This issue consistently appears on two machines I have access to, but I have not tested on others.

Comment: I had the exactly same problem, and found it has nothing to do with Windows 10. Instead, the culprit is .NET 4.7 (which is bundled in "Creators Update").

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and also after Win 10 creators update.

This wrapper class using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization worked for me:

```
public class SynchronizedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    public SynchronizedObservableCollection()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public SynchronizedObservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public SynchronizedObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _lockObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. Unfortunately, the problem still persists for me after implementing it.