# Updating ObservableCollection on dispatcher thread causes UI to freeze

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

When updating my `ObservableCollection`, I was getting this error:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its
>   SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4461682/279516) as a guide, I thought this code would work:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _userMessages = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public void AddUserMessage(string message)
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        Action action = () =>
        {
            this._userMessages.Add(message);
        };

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
    }
}
```

However, my UI now freezes when calling `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. What am I doing incorrectly?

Note: I needed to do this because I'm (sometimes) updating my `ObservableCollection` from events.

Comment: what happens in userMessages.CollectionChanged ?

Comment: @Filip I have not overridden any functionality in `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
```

You invoke your action synchronously and it causes UI to freeze.

Comment: Yes, but it largely negates the use of `lock()` here.