# Insert delay/wait in code c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

```
    public void OpenUpForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (forms.Count == numberoftimes)
        {
            forms.ForEach(f =>
            {
                f.Close(); 
                f.Dispose(); 
            });
            forms.Clear(); 
            //Need Delay Here
            return;
        }
        forms.Add(new Form1());
        forms.Last().Show();
    }
```

Hello I have this code, I need to add delay after `forms.Clear();` But im new to coding i couldnt figure it out.
I have tryed with `Task.Delay` and `Thread.Sleep` but it locks my user interface. Is it possible to add a delay that dosent lock the application? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your need for a delay. This seems like dreadful code. If you run it on a slower computer than yours, does it crash? Blue screen? What if it's faster?

Comment: Im adding a numericupdown and want to delay the code for the time selected. Runs ok on slower computers but im open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark the method async and use this:

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
```

will not block the ui thread

```
public async void OpenUpForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (forms.Count == numberoftimes)
    {
        forms.ForEach(f =>
        {
            f.Close(); 
            f.Dispose(); 
        });
        forms.Clear(); 
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return;
    }
    forms.Add(new Form1());
    forms.Last().Show();
}
```

This will behave like so.

- Creates a new task which runs to completion after 2 seconds
- Ui Thread is bubbled back up to continue executing/processing other events
- Once the 2 seconds is up UI thread returns and resumes executing the async method from after the await

Comment: When I debug it I can see the delay timer is set but when I run it it runs like there is no delay (my delay is 7000).

Comment: That's because the operation `Task.Delay(7000)` never stales the calling thread. It starts a new thread running and then returns back to where you called it. It then continues executing. The await keyword ensures the code after the Task.Delay will not execute until the 7 seconds are up.